# MySQL inner join with 2 columns

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, inner-join

I have one table users with 2 fields : id , name  and another table friends with 2 fields : userid1 userid2 .

So this means userid1 is friend with userid2 . I want , with one inner or left join to show this :

userid1 name(got from users table) is friend with userid2 name(got from users table)

something

SELECT * FROM friends INNER JOIN users ON friends.userid1 = users.id AND friends.userid2 = users.id but this is not working.

Any good query with good explanation please?

If, for example I have the next details in the users table : 
ID : 1    NAME : FinalDestiny
ID : 2    NAME : George

and the next details in the friends table : 
ID1 : 1      ID2 : 2

So this means 1 is friend with 2.

I need with one query to get the name of 1 and the name of 2 and to echo that they're friends

FinalDestiny is friend with George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you specify that you want this done with one join, but it looks to me like you need two.  I believe this query will give you what you need:

`SELECT u1.Name, u2.Name

FROM Users u1, Users u2, Friends f

WHERE u1.id = f.userid1 AND u2.id = f.userid2`

I am joining the Users table with the Friends table with on Users.id = Friends.userid1.  Then, I am joining this new table with the Users table on (new table).userid2 = Users.id.  This results in a table with 4 columns.  These columns are the original 2 columns of the Friends table in addition to 2 columns for the names of the friends.  `u1`, `u2`, and `f` and referring to the three tables that were joined.  The users table was joined with the friends table twice.  `u1` is the copy of the Users table that was joined on Friends.userid1 = User.id.  `u2` is the copy of the Users table that was joined on Friends.userid2 = User.id.

From this table with 4 columns, I am selecting only the names of the friends.

Let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: Whats u1.name ? Please do the query using my specifications , users table, friends table and my fields

Answer (score 2):

You check on a user being a friend of itself. Use `OR` in your select to match user's friends:

```
SELECT * FROM friends INNER JOIN users ON friends.userid1 = users.id OR friends.userid2 = users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for example I have the next details in the users table : 
ID : 1    NAME : FinalDestiny
ID : 2    NAME : George

and the next details in the friends table : 
ID1 : 1      ID2 : 2

So this means 1 is friend with 2.

I need with one query to get the name of 1 and the name of 2 and to echo that they're friends

FinalDestiny is friend with George